# SQL case query didn't work

Tags: sql

I have a table where there are two columns, which should technically just be one column. Let's say there are 20 rows in my table, id_col1 has data till row 15, then id_col2 has data from rows 16-20. So in my new table, I'm creating a new column that has data from these 2 columns by using a case statement. But, the new column accepts data from id_col1, but doesn't from id_col2, it's just blank when it should have data from id_col2. My code is as follows:

```
    select 

            case
                when id_col1 is null then id_col2
                else id_col1 end as 'newcol',
            cusip,
            cast (Date as date) as 'Date',
            Price,
            Evaluator,
            Yes_No as 'Accepted'

    into #cloudtemptbl
    from MasterData
    where Date >= '2017-01-01'
    select * from #cloudtemptbl
```

My theory is that the data in id_col2 is binary not string. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use [`COALESCE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) instead.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the table data?

Comment: Please add your table schema.

Comment: Are you sure that *empty* value is actually `NULL`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/r7nAwo6

Comment: Looks like a data type conversion silent failure. Can you post the column definitions so we can see the data types? Also, `ISNULL(id_col1, id_col2)` would be simpler than a case statement here. There are variants of that function depending on which form of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this :

```
when id_col1 is null or id_col1 = '' then id_col2
            else id_col1 end as 'newcol'
```

Comment: I don't have access to that

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `CONVERT` or `CAST` to get the data types to match across both tables.

Work out the data type you're planning on using in the final, combined table. Then use `CAST` or `CONVERT` on any data that doesn't match that type, to get it into the correct format.

Comment: i tried both cast and covert, didn't work. It's driving me nuts lol

Comment: Okay, instead of just saying, "Tried it, didn't work" to all these suggestions, post your queries and the error message that you got.